# What is the Marshal's Quarry?

Tags: dnd-4e, character-creation, theme

While building a character for the newest season of encounters, a  Paladin(Blackguard), I decided to take the Sentinel Marshal Theme. As part of the entry features for the theme you receive the *Marshall's Interdiction* encounter power. The power states:

> **Effect:** The target is immobilized until the end of your next turn. You also mark the target until you end your turn without hitting or missing it with an attack. In addition, you designate the enemy as your marshal’s quarry until the end of the encounter. - Dragon #407.

However, Marshal's Quarry isn't listed anywhere in the compendium or described in the original *[Dragon article](https://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dragon/407/407_CT_Sentinel_Marshals.pdf)* beyond reference the Marshal's interdiction power referencing it. I assume it works similarly to the Hunter's Quarry power of the Ranger class, but if anyone had any sort of errata, faqs, or just anything from the designers/publishers clarifying it I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Marshal's Quarry is just an extra status effect. This power does three things:

- Immobilizes the target til the end of your next turn.
- Marks the target until you stop attacking it
- Designates it as your Marshal's Quarry.

Marshall's Quarry has little effect unless you take the utility powers associated with the theme. Much like the Ranger's "Hunter's Quarry" it designates the target as a pursuit target. The utility power benefits specific to the mechanic are as follows:

- L2: shift a square closer to your quarry as free action(+2 speed, +2 def vs OAs all the time)
- L6: get some temp HP if you hit your quarry (defense bonus with any hit)
- L10: regain power when you kill your quarry (free healing and save you get with any kill you use this on).

The only other mechanic that is related to this is that at L10 you get a +2 to saves against status effects applied by your quarry. But that's it, so these four things are all this effect does.